# Why is this dormer flashing causing a leak?

Tags: leak, roof, exterior, flashing

This roof was repaired about 6 years ago and is now slowly leaking when there is a heavy downpour.  The leak is located close to the center point in between the outer wall and the dormer.  It is directly underneath the right hand side edge of the dormer flashing shown below.  I'm pretty sure it wasn't properly installed because there is a smaller leak next to the other dormer which doesn't get hit by the rain as hard.  How should this be fixed?  Is there a short-term laymen-friendly solution to prevent further damage?  Thanks.
[image]

Comment: There should be flashing between the dormer and roof. If you can bend the roof tiles without damage, slide a flashing up under them, and at least 8" up the dormer, then use adhesive and silicone to seal. Without seeing anything underneath, I highly doubt a bead of silicone will help here at all.

Comment: There is flashing under the tiles already.  You can see the white dashed lines a couple inches from the dormer.  The leak is not directly adjacent to the dormer, but rather to the right of the large V-shaped piece of metal in the center of the photo.